# JQuery button is not displaying an alert

Tags: jquery

I am learning jquery and I am having difficulty running the following extremely simple code.

My HTML looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>JQUERY</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" id="testbutton" value="test" />

</body>
```

My script.js looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert('document is ready');
});
$('#testbutton').click(function(){
  alert('button clicked');
});
```

When I load the page in browser ... I get the first alert when the document is loaded (so I am sure that I am at least using the correct library and it is getting downloaded etc).

However, when I click my button I do not see the second alert that says "button has been clicked"

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `click` handler needs to go inside your `$(document).ready`, to ensure that it is bound when the DOM is ready, and the element is guaranteed to be available for Javascript processing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('document is ready');

    // bind a click handler to #testbutton when the DOM has loaded
    $('#testbutton').click(function(){
      alert('button clicked');
    });
});
```

From the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Introducing_$(document).ready()):

> This is the first thing to learn about
>   jQuery: If you want an event to work
>   on your page, you should call it
>   inside the $(document).ready()
>   function. Everything inside it will
>   load as soon as the DOM is loaded and
>   before the page contents are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to bind your event handler inside the $(document).ready() event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert('document is ready');

  $('#testbutton').click(function(){
   alert('button clicked');
  });
});
```

This makes sure the DOM is loaded before your other script gets executed. See if this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You also need that click binding inside a `document.ready`, like this:

```
$(function(){      //short for $(document).ready(function(){
  alert('document is ready');
  $('#testbutton').click(function(){
    alert('button clicked');
  });
});
```

The *why?* is that the selector `$('#testbutton')` won't find the element `id="testbutton"` if it's not ready when the selector runs, so it needs to be run after the element in the page, or in a `document.ready` handler like above.